# Expressing there is at least X, at most X, or exactly X in formal logic at the front of a statement.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let's say I want to express the following:

"There are at least 6 people that have eaten broccoli in the last 30 days."  or "There are at most 6 people that have eaten broccoli in the last 30 days." or even "There are exactly 6 people that have eaten broccoli in the last 30 days."

How would those three statements be most efficiently and distinctly expressed in formal logic?

Would floor and ceiling symbols add sufficient context?

Answer (score 0):

"At least $n$ $\phi$" means "There exist at least $n$ objects which are mutually distinct and all of which have the property $\phi$". Formalized:

$$\exists^{\geq n} = \\ \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots \land x_1 \neq x_n \land \ldots \land x_{n-1} \neq x_n \land \phi(x_1) \land \ldots \phi(x_n))$$

"At most $n$ $\phi$" means "not at least $n+1$ $\phi$":

$$\exists^{\leq n} = \\ \neg \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_{n+1} (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots \land x_1 \neq x_n \land \ldots x_n \neq x_{n+1} \land \phi(x_1) \land \ldots \phi(x_{n+1}))$$

Finally, "exactly one $n$" is the same as "at least $n$ and not $n+1$":

$$\exists^{= n} = \\ \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots x_1 \neq x_{n+1} \land \ldots x_{n-1} \neq x_n \land \phi(x_1) \land \ldots \land \phi(x_n) \land \neg \exists x_{n+1} (x_1 \neq x_{n+1} \land \ldots \land x_n \neq x_{n+1} \land \phi(x_{n+1})))$$

Equivalently, one could formulate "exactly one $n$" as "there exist $n$ objects such that the elements satisfying $\phi$ are exactly these elements":

$$\exists^{=n} = \\ \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n (x_1 \neq x_2 \land \ldots \land x_1 \neq x_n \land \ldots \land x_{n-1} \neq x_n \land \forall y (\phi(y) \leftrightarrow (y = x_1 \lor \ldots \lor y = x_n)))$$